# Javascript: Convert string to computable

Tags: javascript

please someone help me about my javascript code. I want to convert string to be computable.
Example:
var string = "34.5 + 30";

the javascript function or code will automatically compute my string value. So the result will be 64.5 with a float or decimal data type.

hope someone can answer my query.

Comment: Will there only be addition `+` operation here? Is it possible, there will be `*`, `-`, or `/` operations also.

Comment: This exercise is designed to teach you how to write your own programming language. In string form `34.5 + 30` is just a sequence of bytes. If we `tokenize` it, we can break it into meaningful tokens, `34.5`, `"+"`, and `30`. If we `parse` it, we can build a syntax tree like `{ operation: "+", arguments: [34.5, 30] }`. Writing our own `evaluate`, we can compute the final result, `74.5`. I think you will find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168750/633183) to be extremely helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval` function.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

The eval() function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

But there is a security issue in this.

> Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is
> far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use
> eval(). See Never use eval()!, below.

```js
var myString = "34.5 + 30";
console.log(eval(myString));
```

Since `eval` has some security issues, its always adviced not to use it. You could either make use of some custom libraries or implement your own parsing logic.

Please find a small paring logic from my side.

**Please note,** this evaluates the mathematical expressions linearly. This **doesnot** works with **BODMAS** rule or **will not evaluate any complex expression**. This is to evaluate a mathematical expression that contains only numbers, and basic operators such as `+, -, * and /`. If you wish to have custom validations you could build on top of this or can implement a solution of your own.

I have added the description as code comment

```js
const myString = "34.5 + 30";

// Regex to split the expression on +, -, *, / and spaces
const isNumeric = /(?=[-+*\/(\s+)])/;

// Valid operators
const operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];

// Split the string into array
const expressionArray = myString.split(isNumeric);

// Object to hold the result and the operator while parsing the array generated
const result = { result: 0, operator: '' };

// loop though each node in the array
// If an operator is found, set it to result.operator
// If not an operator, it will be a number
// Check an operator is already existing in result.operator
// If then perform the operation with the current node and result and clear the result.operator
expressionArray.forEach((node) => {
  const trimmedNode = node.trim();
  if (trimmedNode) {
    if (operators.indexOf(trimmedNode) === -1) {
      if (result.operator) {
        switch (result.operator) {
          case '+':
            result.result += Number(node);
            break;
          case '-':
            result.result -= Number(node);
            break;
          case '*':
            result.result *= Number(node);
            break;
          case '/':
            result.result /= Number(node);
            break;
            result.operator = '';
        }
      } else {
        result.result += Number(node);
      }
    } else {
      result.operator = trimmedNode;
    }
  }
});
console.log(result.result);
```

Comment: @HevinSiatonEbarle What all operators do you have? Is it just `+` or other operators?

Comment: @HevinSiatonEbarle See [_"Never use eval!"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) on the MDN wiki

Comment: @HevinSiatonEbarle please approve the answer, if this is what you are looking for.