# Recursive calculator with adding and substracting

Tags: python, function, recursion, calculator, nested-function

I've made nested function that takes 3 separate arguments - each function takes one: `(arg1)(operation)(arg2)`

```
def simple_functional_calc(arg1: int):
    def inner_functional_calc(operation: str):
        import operator
        ops = {
            '+': operator.add,
            '-': operator.sub
        }

        def inner_inner_functional_calc(arg2: int):
            return ops[operation](arg1, arg2)
        return inner_inner_functional_calc
    return inner_functional_calc
```

There is also other idea (without imports):

```
def calculator(arg1: int):
    def inner_calc(operation: str):
        def add(arg2: int):
            return arg1 + arg2

        def sub(arg2: int):
            return arg1 - arg2

        if operation == '+':
            return add
        elif operation == '-':
            return sub
    return inner_calc
```

in this example `print(calculator(1)('+')(7))` results in `8`. The problem is to make function which can take any number of arguments and return result when the last argument is '='. Example: `print(calculator(2)('+')('5')('-')(3)('-')(1)('='))` results in `3`. Any hints? (if it is possible i would prefer not to use any imports and global variables!)

Comment: You can use `def func(*arg)` so that func can take variable number of args, which will be saved in `arg` as a tuple. You can see the args number inside func with `len(arg)` and access them as a normal tuple.

Comment: but the arguments have to be passed in specyfic order as i wrote: print(calculator(2)('+')('5')('-')(3)('-')(1)('='))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write calculator to take any input `t`, and a default lambda accululator, `r` -

```py
def calculator(t, r = lambda a: a):
  if isinstance(t, int):
    return lambda next: \
      calculator(next, lambda _: r(t))
  elif t == "+":
    return lambda next: \
      calculator(next, lambda a: r(0) + a)
  elif t == "-":
    return lambda next: \
      calculator(next, lambda a: r(0) - a)
  # else any other operation:
    # ...
  elif t == "=":
    return r(0)
```

```py
print(calculator(2)('+')(5)('-')(3)('-')(1)('='))
```

```
2 + 5 - 3 - 1 =
7 - 3 - 1 =
4 - 1 =
```

```py
3
```

This works reliably well, even when "overriding" operations -

```py
calculator(5)("+")("-")(3)("=")       # 2
calculator(5)("+")("-")("+")(3)("=")  # 8
```

However not so much when multiple numbers are provided without operations to combine them -

```py
calculator(5)(4)(3)("=")  # 5
```

This is a toy program for what seems like a toy assignment, however I think there is a lot to learn if you consider pocket calculator arithmetic can be a fun way to implement your first language. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168750/633183) for details.

To clarify what I mean, consider this dramatically simplified version of `calc` -

```py
def calc(t, r = ()):
  if t == "=":
    return r
  else:
    return lambda next: \
      calc(next, (*r, t))
```

```py
print(calc(2)('+')(5)('-')(3)('-')(1)('='))
print(calc(5)("+")("-")(3)("="))
print(calc(5)("+")("-")("+")(3)("="))
print(calc(5)(4)(3)("="))
```

```
(2, '+', 5, '-', 3, '-', 1)
(5, '+', '-', 3)
(5, '+', '-', '+', 3)
(5, 4, 3)
```

Instead of trying to compute everything in super complex function, `calc` forms an resulting *expression*, `r`. In the final step, rather than returning the expression as output, we can tokenize and parse to compute the desired result, using your intended order of operations -

```py
def calc(t, r = ()):
  if t == "=":
    return eval(parse(tokenize(r))) # <--
  else:
    return lambda next: \
      calc(next, (*r, t))

def tokenize(t):
  # ...

def parse(t):
  # ...

def eval(t):
  # ...
```

This gives you the ability to aptly handle expressions like

```py
calc(5)(3)("+")(1)(0)(7)("*")(2)("=")
```

Perhaps tokenizing as -

```
53 + 107 * 2 =
```

And evaluating with left-to-right order of operations -

```
53 + 107 * 2 =
160 * 2 =
```

```py
320
```

Or evaluating with PEMDAS, for example -

```
53 + 107 * 2 =
53 + 214 =
```

```py
267
```

Implementing `tokenize`, `parse`, and `eval` is left as an exercise for the reader. If you have any questions, I am happy to assist.