# Using Function() constructor as a closure

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function simpleOperations(operation) {
    let myFanction = new Function('a', 'b', 'a ' + operation + ' b');
    return myFanction
}

let sum = simpleOperations("+")
let multiplicate = simpleOperations("*")

console.log("your sum is: " + sum(3,7));
console.log("your product is: " + multiplicate(3,7));
```

and instead of getting:

```
your sum is: 10
your product is: 21
```

I'm getting this:

```
your sum is: undefined
your product is: undefined
```

Do you have any thoughts on how to fix it? :)

Comment: You are missing `return`.

Comment: Probably useful: [Are Variable Operators Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5834318) - encode your operators in a table, instead of constructing functions on the fly.

Comment: Missing return in body of the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text body of the function needs to `return` the value, otherwise your `a + b` or `a * b` etc will just be an unused expression.

```js
function simpleOperations(operation) {
    let myFanction = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a ' + operation + ' b');
    return myFanction
}

let sum = simpleOperations("+")
let multiplicate = simpleOperations("*")

console.log("your sum is: " + sum(3,7));
console.log("your product is: " + multiplicate(3,7));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Function` is an anti-pattern. It's one degree away from `eval` and there's always a better way to write things, especially considering JavaScript already supports first-class functions -

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b

console.log("your sum is: " + add(3,7))
console.log("your product is: " + multiply(3,7))
```

```
your sum is: 10
your product is: 21
```

If instead you want to access functions using `"+"` and `"*"` strings, you can create a simple lookup and throw an Error when a particular operation is not supported -

```js
const operations = { 
  "+": (a, b) => a + b,
  "*": (a, b) => a * b 
}
  
function simpleOperations(op) {
  const f = operations[op]
  if (f == null)
    throw Error(`unsupported operation: ${op}`)
  return f
}
  
const add = simpleOperations("+")
const multiply = simpleOperations("*")

console.log("your sum is: " + add(3,7))
console.log("your product is: " + multiply(3,7))

const divide = simpleOperations("/")  // <- not yet implemented
```

```
your sum is: 10
your product is: 21
Error: unsupported operation: /
```

Implementing a simple calculator is a great way to learn how to write your first programming language. If this sort of thing interests you, see this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168750/633183).