# Is there a way to filter an array of objects with multiple dynamic conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, filtering

I have an array of objects `options` similar to:

```
const options = [
    {
        "apiName": "tomato",
        "category": "veggie",
        "color": "red",
        "price": "90"
    },
    {
        "apiName": "banana",
        "category": "fruit",
        "color": "yellow",
        "price": "45"
    },
    {
        "apiName": "brinjal",
        "category": "veggie",
        "color": "violet",
        "price": "35"
    },
]
```

I would like to filter this array using a filtering conditions object  (generated dynamically) similar to

```
Example filterGroup 1
let filterGroup = {
      type: 'and',
      filters: [
        {
          key: 'category',
          condition: 'is',
          value: 'veggie'
          type: 'filter'

        },
        {
          key: 'price',
          condition: 'is less than',
          value: '45',
          type: 'filter'
        }
      ]
    }

Example filterGroup 2
let filterGroup = {
      key: 'category',
      condition: 'is',
      value: 'veggie'
      type: 'filter'
    }
```

In the above `filterGroup` object each element in the filters array acts as individual filters that each `option` in `options` should satisfy.
Possible values of `condition` are `is`, `is not`, `is less than` and `is greater than`.

**How can I filter the `options` array using the `conditions` object in the most efficient way using JavaScript?**

What I have tried (REPL Link - https://replit.com/@pcajanand/DarkseagreenEnlightenedTests#index.js),

Made some filter function creators

```
const eq = (propertyAccessKey, compareValue) => (item) => (item[propertyAccessKey] === compareValue)
const ne = (propertyAccessKey, compareValue) => (item) => (item[propertyAccessKey] === compareValue)
const lt = (propertyAccessKey, compareValue) => (item) => (item[propertyAccessKey] < compareValue)
const gt = (propertyAccessKey, compareValue) => (item) => (item[propertyAccessKey] > compareValue)
```

Made a function to create filter function with an individual filter (type = filter)

```
const makeFilterFunction = ({condition, value, key}) => {
      if (condition === 'is') {
      return (eq(key, value))
    } else if (condition === 'is greater than') {
      return (gt(key, value))
    } else if (condition === 'is less than') {
      return (lt(key, value))
    } else if (condition === 'is not') {
      return (ne(key, value))
    }
}
```

Created filter functions and pushed them into an array,

```
let fnArray = []
if (filters.type === 'and') {
  filters.filters.forEach((filter) => {
    fnArray.push(makeFilterFunction(filter))
  })
} else if (filters.type === 'filter') {
  fnArray.push(makeFilterFunction(filters))
}
```

Loop through every option, check every filter condition against it, then pushed items passing all conditions to an array as filtered result.

```
const res = opts.reduce((acc, next) => {
  let fnIndex = 0
  let fnArrayLength = fnArray.length
  let itemPassed = true
  while(fnIndex < fnArrayLength) {
    const fnPassed = fnArray[fnIndex](next)
    if (!fnPassed) {
      itemPassed = false
      break
    }
    fnIndex += 1
  }
  if (itemPassed) {
    return acc.concat(next)
  } else {
    return acc
  }
}, [])
```

While this works (I think?), I want to know if there is some other more efficient way to do this. Or if I'm completely missing something and overcomplicating things.

TLDR - Want to filter an array of objects with multiple chained conditions.

Non-native English speaker here, sorry if the question is ambiguous.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: The `filterGroup` examples are not the same, the first one has a top level `type` property. What is that ?

Comment: do you have only one nested filter, or could it be unlimited?

Comment: @Titus basically filterGroup can come in either form. If it only has a single filter it will have type = 'filter'. Otherwise it will have type = 'and' (meaning all the filters are combined using and).

Comment: @NinaScholz No, for our use case only one level of nesting. So there wont be anything like (Filter1 & Filter 2) || Filter 3. But If I can cover something like that, it would be a bonus.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are essentially implementing a domain specific language where you need to convert language expressions into runnable programs. For this particular language, we wish to convert expressions from plain JavaScript objects into a JavaScript **function** -

```js
function evaluate(expr) {
  switch (expr?.type) {
    case "filter":
      return v => evaluateFilter(v, expr)
    case "and":
      return v => expr.filters.every(e => evaluate(e)(v))
    case "or":
      return v => expr.filters.some(e => evaluate(e)(v))
  //case ...:
  //  implement any other filters you wish to support
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported filter expression: ${JSON.stringify(expr)}`)
  }
}
```

Then we take the resulting function and plug it directly into `Array.prototype.filter`. The basic usage will look like this -

```
myinput.filter(evaluate({ /* your domain-specific expression here */ })
```

Next, `evaluateFilter` is the low-level function that you have already written. Here it is implemented as a single function, but you could separate it more if you desire -

```js
function evaluateFilter(t, {key, condition, value}) {
  switch (condition) {
    case "is":
      return t?.[key] == value
    case "is greater than":
      return t?.[key] > value
    case "is less than":
      return t?.[key] < value
    case "is not":
      return t?.[key] != value
  //case ...:
  //  implement other supported conditions here
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported filter condition: ${condition}`)
  }
}
```

Given some `input` such as -

```js
const input = [
  { type: "fruit", name: "apple", count: 3 },
  { type: "veggie", name: "carrot", count: 5 },
  { type: "fruit", name: "pear", count: 2 },
  { type: "fruit", name: "orange", count: 7 },
  { type: "veggie", name: "potato", count: 3 },
  { type: "veggie", name: "artichoke", count: 8 }
]
```

We can now write simple expressions with a single filter -

```js
input.filter(evaluate({
  type: "filter",
  condition: "is",
  key: "type", value: "fruit"
}))
```

```js
[
  {
    "type": "fruit",
    "name": "apple",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "fruit",
    "name": "pear",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "fruit",
    "name": "orange",
    "count": 7
  }
]
```

Or rich expressions that combine multiple filters using `and` and/or `or` -

```js
input.filter(evaluate({
  type: "and",
  filters: [
    {
      type: "filter",
      condition: "is not",
      key: "type",
      value: "fruit"
    },
    {
      type: "filter",
      condition: "is greater than",
      key: "count",
      value: "3"
    }
  ]
}))
```

```js
[
  {
    "type": "veggie",
    "name": "carrot",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "type": "veggie",
    "name": "artichoke",
    "count": 8
  }
]
```

The evaluator is recursive so you can combine `and` and/or `or` in any imaginable way -

```js
input.filter(evaluate({
  type: "or",
  filters: [
    {
      type: "filter",
      condition: "is less than",
      key: "count",
      value: 3
    },
    {
      type: "and",
      filters: [
        {
          type: "filter",
          condition: "is not",
          key: "type",
          value: "fruit"
        },
        {
          type: "filter",
          condition: "is greater than",
          key: "count",
          value: "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}))
```

```js
[
  {
    "type": "veggie",
    "name": "carrot",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "type": "fruit",
    "name": "pear",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "veggie",
    "name": "artichoke",
    "count": 8
  }
]
```

Expand the snippet to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
function evaluate(expr) {
  switch (expr?.type) {
    case "filter":
      return v => evaluateFilter(v, expr)
    case "and":
      return v => expr.filters.every(e => evaluate(e)(v))
    case "or":
      return v => expr.filters.some(e => evaluate(e)(v))
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported filter expression: ${JSON.stringify(expr)}`)
  }
}

function evaluateFilter(t, {key, condition, value}) {
  switch (condition) {
    case "is":
      return t?.[key] == value
    case "is greater than":
      return t?.[key] > value
    case "is less than":
      return t?.[key] < value
    case "is not":
      return t?.[key] != value
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported filter condition: ${condition}`)
  }
}

const input = [
  { type: "fruit", name: "apple", count: 3 },
  { type: "veggie", name: "carrot", count: 5 },
  { type: "fruit", name: "pear", count: 2 },
  { type: "fruit", name: "orange", count: 7 },
  { type: "veggie", name: "potato", count: 3 },
  { type: "veggie", name: "artichoke", count: 8 }
]

console.log(input.filter(evaluate({
  type: "filter",
  condition: "is",
  key: "type", value: "fruit"
})))

console.log(input.filter(evaluate({
  type: "and",
  filters: [
    {
      type: "filter",
      condition: "is not",
      key: "type",
      value: "fruit"
    },
    {
      type: "filter",
      condition: "is greater than",
      key: "count",
      value: "3"
    }
  ]
})))

console.log(input.filter(evaluate({
  type: "or",
  filters: [
    {
      type: "filter",
      condition: "is less than",
      key: "count",
      value: 3
    },
    {
      type: "and",
      filters: [
        {
          type: "filter",
          condition: "is not",
          key: "type",
          value: "fruit"
        },
        {
          type: "filter",
          condition: "is greater than",
          key: "count",
          value: "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})))
```

Comment: Amazing!, This is exactly what I was hoping to achieve. Just to make things clear, you are recursively calling the evaluator function in until the expression is just a single filter right? Edit: my bad, I only read the code at first you made it clear it was recurrsive

Comment: happy to help! yes that is correct. for **compound** expressions like `and` and `or`, we use `evaluate` recursively to evaluate each of the combined sub-expressions. `{type: "filter", ...}` is a simple expression with no sub-expressions to evaluate and so the recursive `evaluate` eventually stops :D

Comment: in this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168750/633183) we go thru an exercise of implementing a basic programming language for computing pocket calculator arithmetic. in another exercise, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57739457/633183) explores extending javascript's capabilities using javascript itself. if you have any questions, i'm happy to assist ^^

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I will be sure to check those out.

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify this a little, here is an example:

```js
const options = [{
    "apiName": "tomato",
    "category": "veggie",
    "color": "red",
    "price": "90"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "banana",
    "category": "fruit",
    "color": "yellow",
    "price": "45"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "brinjal",
    "category": "veggie",
    "color": "violet",
    "price": "35"
  },
];

const filterGroup1 = {
  type: 'and',
  filters: [{
      key: 'category',
      condition: 'is',
      value: 'veggie',
      type: 'filter'

    },
    {
      key: 'price',
      condition: 'is less than',
      value: '45',
      type: 'filter'
    }
  ]
}

const filterGroup2 = {
  key: 'category',
  condition: 'is',
  value: 'veggie',
  type: 'filter'
}

const filterFunConstructor = {
"is": (propertyAccessKey, compareValue) => (item) => (item[propertyAccessKey] === compareValue),
"is not": (propertyAccessKey, compareValue) => (item) => (item[propertyAccessKey] !== compareValue),
"is less than": (propertyAccessKey, compareValue) => (item) => (item[propertyAccessKey] < compareValue),
"is greater than": (propertyAccessKey, compareValue) => (item) => (item[propertyAccessKey] > compareValue)
}

const process = (options, filterGroup) => {
  let filterFun;
  if (filterGroup.type === 'and') {
    filterFun = filterGroup.filters.reduce((a, c) => (a.push(filterFunConstructor[c.condition](c.key, c.value)), a),[]);
  } else {
    filterFun = [filterFunConstructor[filterGroup.condition](filterGroup.key, filterGroup.value)]
  }
  return options.filter((v) => filterFun.every((fn) => fn(v)));
}

console.log(process(options, filterGroup1));
console.log(process(options, filterGroup2));
```

What this does is to use the `filterGroup` to create an array of functions and then filter the `options` array to see if the items in there will return `true` when run through all those functions.

Comment: This is great, helped me realize I was indeed overcomplicating things. Thanks for the Answer!

Answer (score -1):

You could build functions and filter the data. This approach features nested search conditions.

A small view to filtering with `type: 'and'`:

The filtering with a condition retuns a function which acts later as callback for filtering. That means it takes one object from `options` and peforms a check with a given condition and the handed over data, both from the filter as well from the option's object.

Now for `and`, you need more than one function and of all functions return `true`, the object should be in the result set.

To check more than one function, [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) cones in handy by checking all items and return either `true`, if all conditions are `true` or `false`, if one condition returns `false`. The iteration breaks in this case as well.

Let's have a look to the returned function:

```
(c => o => c.every(fn => fn(o)))(filters.map(filterBy))
```

It is a closure over `c` with the value of all needed filter conditions

```
(c =>                          )(filters.map(filterBy))
```

the finally returned function is the inner part

```
      o => c.every(fn => fn(o))
```

where every constraint function is taken and called with the object from `options`.

```js
const
    conditions = {
        'is': (a, b) => a === b,
        'is less than': (a, b) => a < b
    },
    options = [{ apiName: "tomato", category: "veggie", color: "red", price: "90" }, { apiName: "banana", category: "fruit", color: "yellow", price: "45" }, { apiName: "brinjal", category: "veggie", color: "violet", price: "35" }],
    filterGroup = { type: 'and', filters: [{ key: 'category', condition: 'is', value: 'veggie', type: 'filter' }, { key: 'price', condition: 'is less than', value: '45', type: 'filter' }] },
    filterGroup2 = { key: 'category', condition: 'is', value: 'veggie', type: 'filter' },
    filterBy = ({ type, filters, key, condition, value}) => {
        if (type === 'filter') return o => conditions[condition](o[key], value);
        if (type === 'and') return (c => o => c.every(fn => fn(o)))(filters.map(filterBy));
    };

console.log(options.filter(filterBy(filterGroup)));
console.log(options.filter(filterBy(filterGroup2)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Although, I didn't quite understand what is happening in the 'and' case, would you be kind enough to walk me through?