# Making JavaScript calculator without eval() ? is possible or impossible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, functional-programming, eval

I found it very hard to program a calculator that is similar to a phone calculator.
Yes. using eval() and Function () constructor is easy..

But I think it's not a good practice.

Is there any other way? Maybe in functional approach of programming.

I'm searching for answers,maybe methods on how to really program a calculator in JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe you will find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168750/633183) to be useful

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm